# How to install cacti in SUSE Linux Enterprise Server?

Tags: software-installation, suse, cacti

I want to install [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) in my SUSE Enterprise Server 11 Edition.

What steps do I need to do to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

According to the cacti [download page](http://www.cacti.net/download_cacti.php) you can install it in SuSE using `yast`.
That should give you all of the dependencies (if not installed yet) as well:
MySQL, PHP, RRDTool, net-snmp.

Once the requirements are met in this way, and if the version of cacti supplied by `yast` is not recent enough, you can then update it with the version from the download page.

Answer (score 0):

For SLES 12.4 you have to run

`zypper ar https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:/monitoring/SLE_12_SP4/server:monitoring.repo`

in order `cacti` becomes available in `yast`.